# Convert DateTime into Date only, inside of the SELECT SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL statement

```
SELECT NO, MEMBID, DATEFROM, DATETO from Member where MEMBID ='xxyy'
```

I get a return where the dates are in DateTime format. I only want them to be in Date format.

I have tried:-

```
SELECT NO, MEMBID, CONVERT(DATEFROM, GETDATE()), DATETO from Member where MEMBID ='xxyy'

SELECT NO, MEMBID, CAST(DATEFROM as DATE()), DATETO from Member where MEMBID ='xxyy'
```

these don't seem to be working.

I need to convert inside the SQL Statement itself. Been looking around on Google but can't seem to find anything. Any insights?

**EDIT :-**
What finally worked for me is the following conversion technique.

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFROM, 101)

Comment: Is this "SQL Server"? or some other SQL implementation?  Please tag appropriately.  Also, how are you retrieving these values? Are you just looking in a management tool, or are you querying them from application code?  For example, there is a `DATE` type in SQL Server, but that translates to `DateTime` in .Net because there's no `Date` type defined.

Comment: my SQL version - MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no format in a `DateTime` or `Date` object.  That only comes with the display of the data.

You were very close with the Convert, but needed just the [output format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFROM, 101)
```

This will output the `DATEFROM` column as `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @Philo Then show us what you tried, because your result doesn't make much sense

Comment: This is what finally worked for me:-
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFROM, 101)

Comment: even tho you changed your answer after i posted my answer, i will give u the credit.

Comment: @Philo Its true, though I had just gotten back from lunch and realized my error.  I had the edit fixed and was saving it just as you posted your comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a query that casts date time in date.

```
select cast('2014-06-04 00:00:00.000' as date)
```

Comment: Sorry I primarily use sql server 2008 and up. I'm guessing you are on a prior version.

Comment: my SQL version - MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT NO, MEMBID, CAST(DATEFROM AS DATE), DATETO from Member where MEMBID ='xxyy'
```

for SQL SERVER 2012

it should be

```
SELECT NO, MEMBID, CONVERT(date, DATEFROM), DATETO from Member where MEMBID ='xxyy'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/287dd/6 example

Comment: is it MS SQL server ? which version?

Comment: my SQL version - MS SQL 2012